# ArrayList in Class A and user trigger the output from Class B. How do I correctly get an output from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, getter-setter

I doing a bigger school project (first part of basic objective programming in java - so not touched extended, polyphorism etc yet, thats next part), but run in to a small problem and tried for couple of days to find solution (thru books and internet). I constructed different ArrayLists in one class and different classes (at least two) should get access to them.

```
public class Customer 
{   
    
    public void subMenuCustomer() 
    {
        ............code............
        
        int subMenuCust;
        ServiceLogic addCustomer = new ServiceLogic();
        ServiceLogic listAllCustomers = new ServiceLogic();
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Please Choose your preference: ");
            System.out.println("Create account, press \"1\": ");
            System.out.println("Get list of clustomers, press \"2\": ");
            System.out.println("Log out, press \"0\": ";
            subMenuCust = input.nextInt();
            switch(subMenuCust) 
            {
                case 1 ://Call method createCustomer in class ServiceTech to add new customers 
                    addCustomer.createCustomer(name, lastname, ssNo);
                    break;
               case 3 
                    listAllCustomers.getCustomer();
    ............more code..............
              }
        }
```

When user has added details (social secuity number, name and lastname) it is stored in seperate ArrayList. These three ArrayList are added(merge/concat) together to a fourth ArayList, `listCustomer` , so that all elements from the three ArrayList end up in same index [101 -54 Clark Kent, 242-42 Linus Thorvalds, ...].

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ServiceLogic 
{
    //Create new ArrayLists of Strings
    private ArrayList<String> listSSNoCustomers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> listNameCustomers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> listLastnameCustomers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> listCustomers;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public boolean createCustomer(String name, String lastname, String ssNo) //
    {
        System.out.println("Write social security number; ");
        ssNo = input.next();    
        //loop to check that it is a uniq social security number
        for(String ssNumber : listSSNoCustomers)
        {
            if (ssNumber.equals(ssNo))
            {           
                System.out.println("This customer already exist. Must be uniq social security number.");
                return true;
            }
        }   
        //If social security number is not on list, add it 
        //and continue add first name and surname
        listSSNoCustomers.add(ssNo);
        System.out.println(ssNo);
        
        System.out.println("Write firstname; ");
        name = input.next();
        listNameCustomers.add(name);
        System.out.println(name);
        
        System.out.println("Write lastnamame; ");
        surname = input.next(); 
        listSurnameCustomers.add(lastname);
        System.out.println(lastname);           
        return false;
    }
    public void setListCustomer(ArrayList<String> listCustomers)
    {
        this.listCustomers = listCustomers;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getCustomer()
    {
        //ArrayList<String> listCustomers = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i <listSSNoCustomers.size(); i++)
        {
            listCustomers.add(listSSNoCustomers.get(i) + " " + listNameCustomers.get(i) + " " + listFirstnameCustomers.get(i));
        }
    
        System.out.println("customer" + listCustomers);
            
        return listCustomers;
     }
}
```

According to the specification we got, when user want to see list of all customer the outputs should be in format **[666-66 Bruce Wayne, 242-42 Linus Thorvalds, ...]**.
When user (staff) choose to enter details in `class Customer` ( `Case 1` ) it works and elements get stored in the Arraylists for social security numbers, name and lastname (have checked that) .
The problem: when I run I can add customers, but when I try to get a list of customer the output: **[]** . I tried different solution, but same output only empty between the brackets.
So the question, how do I get ouput to work when user choose `case 2` to get a list of all cutomers?

Comment: If you want to use objects then it's a bit strange to split the data in several ArrayLists. Normally you would have a class Customer with three attributes sso, name and lastname with getters and setters and a toString()-method that formats the data the way you want it to get printed. Then you need a ArrayList<Customer>. If you want to print the customers you can just print the toString()-result or use the getter-methods of the class to create another format.

Comment: The thing is that going to be couple of more attributes attributes, like. So depending of the users role (customer, staff...), they can acess different data, add, remove etc.
For example staff can search for a person with a uniq social security number and edit their names.
Staff can create an account to the customer. 
Customer should be able to see it's account and if their is money there. etc.

Have specification what the programme should  do and I'm aware that professionellay, you wouldn't solve it like this. But this is to learn how to programme, how classes work, arraylist etc.